# Evolutionary algorithm python optimization problem

Tags: python, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an assignment about evolutionary algorithm to find the value of `x` to maximize `() = sin(/256)` over the interval `0 ≤  ≤ 255`. Step 1 in the algorithm is to choose an alphabet to represent solutions to the problem. Because candidate solutions are integers in the range `0` to `255`, my professor suggested using 8-bit binary encodings for each individual. Also, he suggested to use a simple array.

However, I am not sure what he meant about 8-bit binary encodings and how to initialize it. Is it just simple `solution=[]`? Thanks in advance. Also, if you happen to have any resources related to this problem, please let me know. I am really lost on this.

Comment: There are also variants of evolutionary optimization where individuals are described by float numbers. Is that prohibited in your assignment?

Answer (score 3):

Any integer can be converted into binary representation, e.g.

```
0 = 00000000
1 = 00000001
2 = 00000010
...
254 = 11111110
255 = 11111111
```

If you need a zero initialization, the initialization is as simple as

```
solution = [0]*8
```

Similarly if you want to initialize with 1s:

```
solution = [1]*8
```

And if you need a random initialization:

```
import numpy as np
solution = list(np.random.randint(0, 2, size=8))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though I know this question has been raised quite some time ago, I think it is worth providing some more details of how to solve such a problem.
A genetic algorithm needs evolutionary operators in order to work. The hint in the assignment is to us a binary **genotype** which is used for sampling, crossover and mutation in each generation. The **phenotype**, however, is the value which has been converted to an integer value. Based on the phenotype the objective value shall be calculated.

One possible setup for a genetic algorithm operating on binary values is to use random binary sampling, uniform crossover and bit flip mutation. In the example below, I have implemented the problem stated in your question this way. I have used the evolutionary (multi-objective) optimization framework [pymoo](https://pymoo.org) for this purpose because it provides already everything which is needed to implement a genetic algorithm out of the box (**Disclaimer**: I am the main developer of pymoo). More information and a getting started guide of **pymoo** can be found [here](https://pymoo.org/getting_started.html).

The optimum for your problem lies where the *sin* function has its maximum. Considering the *sin* function only from *0* to *pi* the maximum is *pi/2*. This corresponds to 128 as an integer value and `10000000` in binary representation.

The following source code using **pymoo** (0.4.1) solves your test problem rather quickly.

**Binary Variable**

```
import numpy as np

from pymoo.algorithms.so_genetic_algorithm import GA
from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize


class MyProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=8,
                         n_obj=1,
                         n_constr=0,
                         xl=0,
                         xu=1)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):

        # get the number of variables to be used
        n = self.n_var

        # create the value of each binary value, e.g. 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
        val = np.full(n, 2) ** np.arange(n)[::-1]

        # convert the input to the corresponding integer value
        x_as_int = (x * val).sum(axis=1)

        # calculate the objective (multiplied by -1 because minimization is assumed)
        out["F"] = - np.sin(x_as_int * np.pi / (2 ** n))


problem = MyProblem()

# initialize the genetic algorithm with binary operators
algorithm = GA(
    pop_size=10,
    sampling=get_sampling("bin_random"),
    crossover=get_crossover("bin_ux"),
    mutation=get_mutation("bin_bitflip"))

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               seed=1,
               verbose=True)

print(res.X.astype(np.int))
print(- res.F)
```

The output:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1.]
```

You can also formulate the problem to optimize a discrete value directly.

**Integer Variable**

```
import numpy as np

from pymoo.algorithms.so_genetic_algorithm import GA
from pymoo.factory import get_sampling, get_crossover, get_mutation
from pymoo.model.problem import Problem
from pymoo.optimize import minimize


class MyProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(n_var=1,
                         n_obj=1,
                         n_constr=0,
                         xl=0,
                         xu=256)

    def _evaluate(self, x, out, *args, **kwargs):
        out["F"] = - np.sin(x * np.pi / 256)


problem = MyProblem()

# initialize the genetic algorithm with binary operators
algorithm = GA(pop_size=15,
               sampling=get_sampling("int_random"),
               crossover=get_crossover("int_sbx", prob=1.0, eta=3.0),
               mutation=get_mutation("int_pm", eta=3.0),
               )

res = minimize(problem,
               algorithm,
               seed=1,
               verbose=True)

print(res.X.astype(np.int))
print(- res.F)
```

In genetic algorithms the variable representation is essential and comes directly along with the evolutionary operators being used.